# Debugging 64 bit application thru Class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am facing problem with debugging my 64 bit application thru a project of type class library ( C#). Here are the steps:

1. I have a class library project.
2. 'Start external program' in debug settings is set to a 64 bit application.
3. Press F5 to start the application
4. Break points are not getting hit.

And if I manually start the application and then attach my project thru attach to process then everything works fine.

Any hint to resolve it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem was different. Actually target framework for application is framwork 4.0. And my class library project is 3.5 based. Changing it to 4.0 resolved the problem.